# How to check the differences between a local and GitHub repository before the pull

Tags: git, github

Before using pull, I want to check if there are any differences between my local and GitHub master.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

`git pull` is really equivalent to running `git fetch` and then `git merge`.  The `git fetch` updates your so-called "remote-tracking branches" - typically these are ones that look like `origin/master`, `github/experiment`, etc. that you see with `git branch -r`.  These are like a cache of the state of branches in the remote repository that are updated when you do `git fetch` (or a successful `git push`).

So, suppose you've got a remote called `origin` that refers to your GitHub repository, you would do:

```
git fetch origin
```

... and then do:

```
git diff master origin/master
```

... in order to see the difference between your `master`, and the one on GitHub.  If you're happy with those differences, you can merge them in with `git merge origin/master`, assuming `master` is your current branch.

Personally, I think that doing `git fetch` and `git merge` separately is generally [a good idea](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).

Comment: if you have setup remote tracking then the commands get a little simpler: 'git fetch' to fetch, 'git diff ..@{u}' to see the differences. I can never keep origin, master, and origin/master straight, so the short commands help a lot

Comment: I tried you method, and got no outputs from `git diff master origin/master` and its opposite, but `git status` tells me `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.` What's going on?

Comment: If `git status` outputs `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.`, you'll need to stage & commit the changes `git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit"` before running `git diff master origin/master`

Answer (score 48):

If you're not interested in the details that `git diff` outputs, you can just run `git cherry` which will output a list of commits your remote tracking branch has ahead of your local branch.

For example:

```
git fetch origin
git cherry master origin/master
```

Will output something like:

```
+ 2642039b1a4c4d4345a0d02f79ccc3690e19d9b1
+ a4870f9fbde61d2d657e97b72b61f46d1fd265a9
```

It indicates that there are two commits in my remote tracking branch that haven't been merged into my local branch.

This also works the other way:

```
git cherry origin/master master
```

It will show you a list of local commits that you haven't pushed to your remote repository yet.

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed. Just to be clear on that: If git cherry result is empty, than there's nothing for cherry picking and my local repo is up to date, right!?

Comment: You can also use the verbose option `-v`, to show the commits messages.
For example : `git cherry -v origin/master master` will output : `+ 2642039b1a4c4d4345a0d02f79ccc3690e19d9b1 Fixed bug`

Answer (score 13):

And another useful command to do this (after `git fetch`) is:

```
git log origin/master ^master
```

This shows the commits that are in *origin/master*, but not in *master*.

You can also do it in the opposite way when doing `git pull` to check what commits will be submitted to the remote.