# What is git status -uno in git

Tags: git

When I type `git status`  There is message saying

```
It took 2.39 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I type `git help status` and read but not understand how to get same as `git status` result

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Git is telling you that because you have many untracked files, the result of `git status` takes longer time than usual.

The fix is to use `git status -uno`. From [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/1.8.1):

> ```
> -u[<mode>]
> --untracked-files[=<mode>]
> ```
>
> Show untracked files.
>
> The mode parameter is optional (defaults to all), and is used to specify the handling of untracked files; when `-u` is not used, the default is normal, i.e. show untracked files and directories.
>
> The possible options are:
>
> **`no` - Show no untracked files**
>
> `normal` - Shows untracked files and directories
>
> `all` - Also shows individual files in untracked directories.